# Frequency distribution in python - not adding to 100%

Tags: python, numpy, plot, frequency, cumsum

I'm trying to get a frequency distribution plot using Python. I have used the cumsum option from numpy, however, only one of the two variables have the frequency that adds to 100%. The code is:

```
values, base=np.histogram(ESM_MAF, bins=40, density=True)
ESM_cum=np.cumsum(values)

val,bas=np.histogram(GW_MAF, bins=40, density=True)
GW_cum=np.cumsum(val)

plt.plot(base[:-1], ESM_cum, 'r')
plt.plot(bas[:-1], GW_cum, 'b')
```

And the output is:
[image: Plot]

The values for the GWAM variable range between 0.01 and 0.5.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I looked at it, and I don't think this is a duplicate. In my case, one of the variables is working fine.

Comment: Looks like you may have been lucky with the one that sums to 1. The histogram density takes bin widths into account and only the integral over `bin value * bin width` actually sums to one. What is different here from the question referred to in the other comment?